# FCM web push notification cannot click on notification link click_action

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have added `click_action` parameters in the `push` function. Here is my sample code.

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
  var title = event.data.json().notification.title;
  var body = event.data.json().notification.body;
  var icon = "/assets/img/logo.png";
  var click_action =
    "http://localhost:4200/#/jobs/notification/" +
    event.data.json().data.job_no;
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: body,
      icon: icon,
      click_action: click_action
    })
  );
});
```

To handle the `click` on the `notification`, defined a `notificationclick` event handler.

For example:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  var redirect_url = event.notification.data.click_action;
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: "window"
      })
      .then(function(clientList) {
        console.log(clientList);
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          var client = clientList[i];
          if (client.url === "/" && "focus" in client) {
            return client.focus();
          }
        }
        if (clients.openWindow) {
          return clients.openWindow(redirect_url);
        }
      })
  );
});
```

But i can't get `click_action` parameter in `notificationclick` function. I want to redirect push notification to givent url in `click_action`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue. I have sent extra parameter in request.
Here is my sample code:

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
  var title = event.data.json().notification.title;
  var body = event.data.json().notification.body;
  var icon = "/assets/img/logo.png";
  var click_action =
    "http://localhost:4200/#/jobs/notification/" +
    event.data.json().data.job_no;
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: body,
      icon: icon,
      data: {
        click_action
      }
    })
  );
});
```

And using `click_action` and here is sample code:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  var redirect_url = event.notification.data.click_action;
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: "window"
      })
      .then(function(clientList) {
        console.log(clientList);
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          var client = clientList[i];
          if (client.url === "/" && "focus" in client) {
            return client.focus();
          }
        }
        if (clients.openWindow) {
          return clients.openWindow(redirect_url);
        }
      })
  );
});
```

Comment: hello guys,can you please help me to sort out this issue. in which file you declared this method. when I am using this method in firebase-messaging-sw.js . I didn't show any reflect

Comment: @NikitaGarg if you still have trouble, try sending message with fcmOptions. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Implementing '*notificationclick*' did not work for me using google's firebase cloud messaging. I used the **fcmOptions** instead, since the implementation is only to do a redirect and the link can be controlled from the server.

Reading into the documentation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive), apparently there is away catered using **fcmOptions** and please note that is has to be a HTTPs link. The document stated to use **fcm_options**, which maybe was outdated as it has [renamed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.MessagePayload) to **fcmOption**

The way to send the message (manually) that worked for me is

```
var message = {
    data: {
      a:1
    },
    notification: {
      title: 'title',
      body: 'body'
    },
    webpush: {
      fcmOptions: {
        link: 'https://www.walcron.com'
      }
    },
    token: VALID_TOKEN
  };
```

For anyone who is doing this Firebase CM, good luck. Spent some several hours going through service-worker, firebase-admin and this GCM documents. In the end, there are very few codes but it's really hard to digest as the scope was so large!